# Functorial cones

Tags: reference-request, derived-categories, dg-categories

This is probably more a reference request than a real question. I was studying dg-categories in order to understand how one can derive a functorial [cone construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)) when a triangulated category (which for what concerns me is often $D^b(X)$, for some smooth projective variety $X$) has a dg-enhancement. I looked only for some papers, but all the ones I found claim the existence of functorial cones without proving the claim. Can anyone point me to somewhere where this is proved and the geometric use of dg-enhancement is stressed? Thank you.

Comment: Well, in derived categories, the cone functor is just the derived functor of the cokernel functor (in general it is a particular homotopy pushout). The choice of an enhancement (DG, $\infty$-categories, model category, ...) gives you a precise strategy to construct derived functors so, in particular, also the cone functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cone construction can be written down very explicitly, just following the definition of mapping cone of chain complexes. Good sources are in my opinion:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401009.pdf Definition 3.7

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210114.pdf paragraph 2.9, where it is discussed how the cone is functorial as a dg-functor from the (homotopy coherent) dg-category of morphisms.

Or, if you like, I wrote both a master and a PhD thesis centered on dg-categories:
https://anisama.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/tesi_mag.pdf (master thesis)
https://anisama.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/tesi.pdf (phd thesis)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

A proof in the context of model categories can be found in Proposition 6.3.5 of Hovey's book *Model Categories*. You could easily rewrite the proof to work in the context of dg-categories, where it is actually easier.

EDIT: [Here](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/Members/gcorti/workgroup.swisk/en/swisk-2007.pdf) is a source that does it for dg-categories, in Section 4.1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I read Toen's notes, but I didn't understand why that was supposed to be e functorial cone construction. Could you expand about it a little please?